# How to allow the user to choose the name for the Start Menu Group on WiX3.5 installer?

Tags: installation, wix, wix3.5

I'm creating an installer using Wix3.5, and I would like to allow the user to choose a name for the Star Menu group where my shortcut will be placed on.

I tried using Properties:

```
<directory id="ProgramMenuFolder">
<directory id="MyStartMenuFolder" name="[START_MENU_GROUP_NAME]">
```

and:

```
<control type="Edit" id="StartMenuGroupName" width="213" height="15" x="56" y="199" property="START_MENU_GROUP_NAME">
```

but the group is created with the literal "START_MENU_GROUP_NAME" and not with the content of the Property.

What is the right way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Directories become properties after CostFinalize.  Therefore have the name attribute be the default value, have a dialog that has an edit box for the id (propertyname) of the Directory.   If the user changes that value it'll change where the shortcuts get created.

```
<Directory Id="MYSTARTMENUFOLDER" Name="My Default Folder Name" />
```

Comment: Hi Christopher, thanks for your help. I did as you mentioned: <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder"> <Directory Id="MYSTARTMENUFOLDER" Name="My Default Folder Name" /> </Directory>. And on the edit: <Control Type="Edit" Id="StartMenuGroupName" Width="213" Height="15" X="56" Y="199" Property="MYSTARTMENUFOLDER" />. But the dialog opens with the edit content: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\My Default Folder Name. If I edit to something like "MyNewValue", on the install phase I get "Could not access network location MyNewValue". Am I missing something? Thanks!